# Resize images from one variable to another

Tags: php, image, variables, insert, resize

ok. I have a variable that is actually a picture

I think that is what creates such a

$ Img = imagecreatefromjpeg ($ srcFile);

Now I would like to resize the image width to  550  but that does not lose the aspect ratio that need to remain the same.

Then the resulting image should be re-registered into a variable so the rest of the code could do the insertion of text and more.

Want to make site demotivation-fakeposters and others.

I found some code from Russians - everything  work but the resize does not work so I wanted to with DataLife Engine and code that make the whole site will agree that the posters and where users will be able to generate and post.

here it is in (for all means not only reduces the images if they are huge)

There are some little hieroglyphs but this is due to the Russian Cyrillic alphabet.

```
<?php

  if (!defined("DATALIFEENGINE"))
  {
    die("Hacking Attemp!");
  }

    function win_to_utf($s) 
{ 
for($i=0, $m=strlen($s); $i<$m; $i++) 
{ 
$c=ord($s[$i]); 
if ($c<=127) 
{$t.=chr($c); continue; } 
if ($c>=192 && $c<=207) 
{$t.=chr(208).chr($c-48); continue; } 
if ($c>=208 && $c<=239) 
{$t.=chr(208).chr($c-48); continue; } 
if ($c>=240 && $c<=255) 
{$t.=chr(209).chr($c-112); continue; } 
if ($c==184) { $t.=chr(209).chr(209); 
continue; }; 
if ($c==168) { $t.=chr(208).chr(129); 
continue; }; 
} 
return $t; 
}
  $dirdem=ROOT_DIR.'/uploads/demotivation/';
 $tpl->load_template('demgen.tpl');
if (isset($_FILES["file"])){
$myfile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$font = str_replace ( "\\", "/", getcwd () )."/arial.ttf";
$font1 = $font;
$headerSize = 33.5;
$textSize = 24.0;
 $imageMargin = 20;
  $spacing = 16;
  $borderPad = 16;
$srcFile = $myfile;

 $header = win_to_utf( $_POST["head"]);
  $text = win_to_utf($_POST["text"]);
 if( !file_exists( $srcFile ) ){
    echo "picture file not found\n";
    exit;
  }
  $img = imagecreatefromjpeg( $srcFile );
  list($w, $h) = getimagesize( $srcFile );

  $ha1 = imagettfbbox($headerSize, 0, $font1, $header );
  $ha2 = imagettfbbox($textSize, 0,$font, $text );

  $wt1 = $ha1[2]-$ha1[0];
  $ht1 = $ha1[1]-$ha1[7];
  $wt2 = $ha2[2]-$ha2[0];
  $ht2 = $ha2[1]-$ha2[7];

  $fw = $w + 8 + $imageMargin * 2 + $borderPad * 2;
  $fh = $h + 8 + $imageMargin * 2 + $borderPad * 2 + $ht1 + $ht2 + $spacing * 3;
  $fon = imagecreatetruecolor($fw, $fh);

  $white = imagecolorallocate( $fon, 255, 255, 255 );
  $black = imagecolorallocate( $fon,   0,   0,   0 );
  imagefill( $fon, 0, 0, $black );

  imagecopy( $fon, $img, $imageMargin + $borderPad + 4, $imageMargin + $borderPad + 4, 0, 0, $w, $h );

  imagerectangle( $fon, $imageMargin + $borderPad + 4 - 3, $imageMargin + $borderPad + 4 - 3,
           $imageMargin + $borderPad + $w + 4 + 2, $imageMargin + $borderPad + $h + 4 + 2, $white );
  imagerectangle( $fon, $imageMargin + $borderPad + 4 - 4, $imageMargin + $borderPad + 4 - 4,
           $imageMargin + $borderPad + $w + 4 + 3, $imageMargin + $borderPad + $h + 4 + 3, $white );

  imagettftext( $fon, $headerSize, 0,
    ($fw - $wt1) / 2, $imageMargin + $borderPad*2 + 8 + $h + $ht1 + $spacing,
    $white, $font1, $header );

  imagettftext( $fon, $textSize, 0,
    ($fw - $wt2) / 2, $imageMargin + $borderPad*2 + 8 + $h + $ht1 + $ht2 + $spacing*2,
    $white, $font, $text );
 $ts=$dirdem.time();
 $ts1='/uploads/demotivation/'.time();
  imagejpeg( $fon, $ts."_demotiv.jpg", 98 );
  imagecolordeallocate( $fon, $black );
  imagecolordeallocate( $fon, $white );
  imagedestroy( $fon );
 $output=$ts1."_demotiv.jpg";
 $wdr= <<<HTML
<center>
     <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <tr><td width="120" height="30"><span style="font-size: xx-small;">» Ïðÿìàÿ ññûëêà:</span></td><td><input type="text" name="head" value="http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$output}" style="border:1px solid #ccc;height:16px;width:300px;padding-left:5px;"></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="120" height="40"><span style="font-size: xx-small;">» Êîä äëÿ ôîðóìà:</span></td><td><input type="text" name="head"  value="[img]http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$output}[/img]" style="border:1px solid #ccc;height:16px;width:300px;padding-left:5px;"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td width="120" height="30"><span style="font-size: xx-small;">» HTML-êîä:</span></td><td><input type="text" name="head" value="&lt;img src=&quot;http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$output}&quot;&gt;" style="border:1px solid #ccc;height:16px;width:300px;padding-left:5px;"></td></tr> 
</form>
</center>
HTML;
} else {
$wdr = <<<HTML
<center>
     <form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<tr><td width="120" height="40"><span style="font-size: xx-small;">» <b>Øàã 1:</b> Èçîáðàæåíèå:</span></td><td><input type="file" name="file"></td></tr>
<tr><td width="120" height="30"><span style="font-size: xx-small;">» <b>Øàã 2:</b> Íàäïèñü ââåðõó:</span></td><td><input type="text" value="Ââåäèòå íàäïèñü..." onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Ââåäèòå íàäïèñü...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Ââåäèòå íàäïèñü...') this.value='';" name="head" style="border:1px solid #ccc;height:16px;width:165px;padding-left:5px;"></td></tr>
<tr><td width="120" height="30"><span style="font-size: xx-small;">» <b>Øàã 3:</b> Íàäïèñü âíèçó:</span></td><td><input type="text" value="Ââåäèòå íàäïèñü..." onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Ââåäèòå íàäïèñü...';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Ââåäèòå íàäïèñü...') this.value='';" name="text" style="border:1px solid #ccc;height:16px;width:165px;padding-left:5px;" value=""></td></tr>
</table><br>
<center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ñîçäàòü" style="border:1px solid #ccc;height:22px;width:200px;padding-left:5px;"></center>
</form>
</center>
HTML;

}
$tpl->set('{cnt}', $wdr);

    $tpl->compile('content');
    $tpl->clear();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean ratio, where the greater of the x or y axis is used as the basis of the ratio: `if (oldwidth > oldheight) ratio = newwidth / oldwidth else ratio = newheight / oldheight`.  You also need to consider a max allowable width and height for copied images.  With PHP GD functions, this is done like so...

```
$imageFilePath = '/original.jpg'; // path to original jpg
$imageSource = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFilePath);
$newImageFilePath = '/new.jpg'; // path to new resized image name
$maxWidth = 100; // the max width you allow
$maxHeight = 100; // the max height you allow
$imgInfo = getimagesize($imageFilePath);
$originalWidth = (int) $imgInfo[0];
$originalHeight = (int) $imgInfo[1];
$originalType = (int) $imgInfo[2];
$conversionRatio = (($originalWidth > $originalHeight) ? $maxWidth / $originalWidth : $maxHeight / $originalHeight); // the important part
$newWidth = $originalWidth * $conversionRatio;
$newHeight = $originalHeight * $conversionRatio;
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
imagecopyresampled($newImage, $imageSource, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $originalWidth, $originalHeight);
imagejpeg($newImage, $newImageFilePath);
```

Comment: but I don't want to save picture. I want to resize it and then write it to another variable so the code can edit it...